# In PHP, is there an advantage to separating return from the calculation?

Tags: php, return-value

In PHP, I have a callback function using `preg_match()` (the exact contents are not relevant I think).

Is it better to calculate the result and assign to a variable, and then return that variable, or should I just return the result?

In other words, is it better to do this:

```
function a() {
   $result = preg_match();
   return $result;
}
```

or

```
function b() {
   return preg_match();
}
```

I'm thinking in terms of code style and performance. Is there a standard I should follow or is it really not important?

Comment: After I read @Mark B's answer below, I did some digging into this.  Using the method described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795425/how-to-get-opcodes-of-php, the first method above does indeed result in one more opcode (an ASSIGN) being called.

Comment: @MPD Wow thanks for that! So if I was really micro-optimising I would go with the second one, but as you said before it doesn't make a lot of difference.

Comment: I don't think it really makes a difference.  I don't put 100% trust in timed for-loops as proof for optimizations.  Being able to explain why and have proof (asm, opcode, bytecode, etc) is key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a performance standpoint there's no difference between the two cases.

Regarding coding style, it's a matter of personal preference. Personally, I would advocate the second, as it's cleaner and easier to read, but I don't think anyone would fault you either way.

Comment: +1 Definitely personal preference.  If the code is simple enough to be self-documenting, I'll often use the single-line approach.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I try to return a variable, as I often want to log that variable somewhere during debug or at least have it available for a `print_r` or `assert` when something goes wonky.  I also tend to do things like

```
$foo = step1($foo);
$foo = step2($foo);
$foo = step3($foo);
return $foo;
```

with string manipulation, and also when I think that requirements may change.  This style makes it easy to comment/uncomment processing.

In general I code for clarity and self-documentation, but also try to anticipate how things may change, and therefore implement things so that impact is minimal.

Answer (score 2):

There'd be a microscopic hit in performance to instantiate the $return variable, but that won't be noticeable in any practical situation. Generally I'd do the direct return, unless I needed to deal with that value further.

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity, have you confirmed or read that the two examples will result in different bytecode?  The output from preg_match has to go somewhere to be returned (stack, temp variable, etc), but I don't know enough about the PHP runtime to say either way.  I believe I have seen cases where a C compiler will generate the same asm, but that is a different ballgame.

Comment: No idea. I've never dug under the hood to see what happens.