# Viewing PHP opcode

Tags: php, opcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get opcodes of PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795425/how-to-get-opcodes-of-php)

As I dig deeper into developing in a specific language, at some point, if possible, I like to view the opcode of the language to give me a deeper understanding of how my code is interpreted or compiled. C/C++ you can usually switch to disassembly view in an IDE, or have the compiler output its instructions. Flash, you can use a utility like flasm to see what's going on..

Is there an option to view PHP's opcode? I took a look through `php` command line parameters, but didn't see anything (maybe I just missed it?).

Comment: @marc: Yes, I missed it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure, but is this what you're looking for? 
http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.list.php

Comment: Nope - I'm looking to see the opcode generated by my code.