# Writing PHP opcode and have it executed. How to do?

Tags: php, opcode, php-internals

How can I write [PHP opcode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.php), save it in a file and make the Zend Engine execute it? Any method or hack is welcome, as long as it does the trick.

Comment: <smile> at "no well-intentioned answers that are not precisely addressing [the] question". Are miserable or angry answers that don't address the question acceptable?

Comment: @halfer ... look at Mo.sch's answer ... PHP-questions always attract such answers ... and did you -1 one me? oh man ...

Comment: No, no -1 from me; I always try to state why I downvote :)

Comment: Why downvote? It's a perfectly valid (and interesting) question.

Comment: @N.B. - yes, it's a good question. The downvotes may have been for the way the question was originally asked, but it has now been nicely improved.

Comment: Would be nice with an update to this question. Some years have passed. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a couple of user-space methods (from plugins) that can deal with Opcodes.

- http://uk.php.net/apc_bin_load (and http://uk.php.net/apc_bin_dump)
- http://uk.php.net/bcompiler_read / http://uk.php.net/bcompiler_write_file

Neither produces plain text however because the opcodes are not designed to be a user-writable language (unlike Parrot).

Comment: that means I could overwrite a cached file with apc_bin_load, I guess ... so next question would be how the nice looking opcode statements relate to the actually used binary representation. do you know something about that? references or so?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795425/how-to-get-opcodes-of-php has some information, mostly referring to "Vulcan Logic Dumper" - http://pecl.php.net/package/vld

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension called [ulopcodes](https://github.com/pmmaga/ulopcodes) that allows you to emit your own opcodes via a function that it exposes to PHP code.

For example:

```
ulopcodes_emit(ZEND_ECHO, "Hello world!");
```

Will create that line in the current oparray which will be executed by the VM.

> This extension is purely educational and not intended to be used in production code.

(Disclaimer: I am the creator of ulopcodes)

Comment: Yes, you can use [vld](https://github.com/derickr/vld) for instance to output the generated opcodes.