# Get PHP Opcodes Dynamically at Runtime

Tags: php, zend-framework, php-extension, php-internals

I want to build a PHP extension that can dynamically inspect every opcode generated from a PHP file and do some checking on that.

I came across several websites and found out a couple of functions like `zend_set_user_opcode_handler`, but I fail to understand how this function can be used to get a complete opcode like `ASSIGN !0, 50`.

I'm aware of a command like `php -d vld.active=1 -d vld.execute=0 -f [filename].php` which I can use to generate PHP opcodes, but as far as I know you can only access the opcodes after the PHP program terminates.

What I'd like to get from the extension is an opcode which is obtained one-by-one (dynamically) as the function executes.

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: I expect xdebug does something similar, can you look at the code for that?

Comment: Generating opcodes is rather difficult since all the stuff for doing so is marked `static` and available only within `zend_compile.c`, so you'd have to duplicate it.

Comment: Might have more look constructing an AST instead.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what you want, but if you want to step through code at the opcode level (and show the opcodes that are executed) then phpdbg supports that.

Comment: Check [this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795425/how-to-get-opcodes-of-php), it should help

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`parsekit`](http://pecl.php.net/package/parsekit) which is available through <kbd>pecl</kbd> which can be downloaded from the [pecl website](http://pecl.php.net/package/parsekit) or installed with:

```
sudo pecl install parsekit
```

## Get OPcodes from a string of PHP code during runtime:

You could use the [`parsekit_compile_string`](https://secure.php.net/parsekit_compile_string)

The syntax for this command is:

```
array parsekit_compile_string ( string $phpcode [, array &$errors [, int $options = PARSEKIT_QUIET ]] )
```

Parameters:

> #### phpcode
>
> A string containing phpcode. Similar to the argument to eval().
>
> #### errors
>
> A 2D hash of errors (including fatal errors) encountered during compilation. Returned by reference.
>
> #### options
>
> One of either PARSEKIT_QUIET or PARSEKIT_SIMPLE. To produce varying degrees of verbosity in the returned output.
>
> #### Return Values
>
> Returns a complex multi-layer array structure as detailed below.

An example usage of this is:

```
<?php
  $ops = parsekit_compile_string('
echo "Foo\n";
', $errors, PARSEKIT_QUIET);

  var_dump($ops);
?>
```

The output is too long to include in this answer but is available on the [documentation page](https://secure.php.net/parsekit_compile_string)

---

## Get OPcodes from a PHP file during runtime:

You could use the [`parsekit_compile_file`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.parsekit-compile-file.php)

Very similar to the above approach but parses a file instead of a string.